# Is there a way to integrate WebSVN RSS into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, websvn

I'm using [WebSvn](http://websvn.tigris.org/) on top of my SVN repository.

WebSvn supports RSS notification (on directory level) for changes made in the repository.
Is there an eclipse plug-in that checks WEbSVN RSS and notifies whenever someone commits and changes the code in the SVN repository. I'm looking for a nice integration within the eclipse package viewer...

-- Yonatan

Answer (score 0):

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/rss-view

or just do a search with:

http://www.google.com/#q=eclipse+rss+plugin

Comment: thanks. I was looking for something that will be more integrated with my Package Explorer / Project Explorer view. so I can get notifications where specific project was changed (or created)